# trying to toggle sound on html video with onclick

Tags: html, audio, video

I am trying to toggle the audio on a html5 video using the `onclick` function so that when you click the video the audio is unmuted, when clicked again it is muted.

however, nothing happens when i click the video

Here is what I have done so far:

```
<p>
<video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" preload="Metadata" onclick="function()" style=" padding-top:15%; width:100%;  height:auto; ">

<source src="Video"></video>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("video").prop('muted', true);

$("video").click( function (){
    $(this).prop('muted', !$(this).prop('muted'));
});

$(".play-video").click( function (){
    $("video").prop('muted', !$("video").prop('muted'));
});
}
</script>
</p>
```

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain in which way it's not working?

Comment: when i click the video the audio doesn't unmute

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually already works. However, you had an unnamed function statement in th `onclick` attribute which might have caused errors depending on your browser/environment (but at least in Firefox it should have worked anyway).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("video").prop('muted', true);

  $("video").click( function (){
      $(this).prop('muted', !$(this).prop('muted'));
  });

  $(".play-video").click( function (){
      $("video").prop('muted', !$("video").prop('muted'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" preload="Metadata" style=" padding-top:15%; width:100%;  height:auto;">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4">
  </video>
</p>
```